# Position text and circle in Highcharts graph dynamically?

Tags: javascript, svg, graph, highcharts

I want to place a few pieces of text in my graphic. Now, I can do this manually, by specifying the xy coordinates. But this is probably not the best way, as the size of the graph can change, and then the positions are hard coded.

Is there a way to derive in a dynamical way the positions of a line? That is: What is the x/y coordinate of the position x=1980? [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/17ed42pa/3/) for it.

```
    options.series.push(series);

    options.chart.events = {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this;
        chart.renderer.text('1970: Arbitrary chosen reference year: All cumulative values are relative to 1970.', xOffset, yOffset)
          .css({
            fontSize: '13px',
            color: '#aaa',
            width: '550px'
          })
          .add();

        chart.renderer.text('1980: observed loss in glacier thickness cumulates to 2 m w.e. since 1970.', 520, 220)
          .css({
            fontSize: '13px',
            color: '#7994d9',
            width: '520px'
          })
          .add();


        chart.renderer.text('1990: cumulative ice loss of 4 m w.e.', 690, 255)
          .css({
            fontSize: '13px',
            color: '#ff6c7f',
            width: '320px'
          })
          .add();

      }
```

Comment: I think that you can use redraw event callback function and inside this function you can get pixel values of your points using Axis.toPixels(value). Here you can see an example how it can work with your circle: http://jsfiddle.net/17ed42pa/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
var points = chart.series[1].points;
for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  var point = points[i];
  if(point.x === 1980) {
    console.log(point.plotX); //263.51049191606
    console.log(point.plotY); //40.81559999999999
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

Adding translated locations to an array:

```
var locations = [];
var points = chart.series[1].points;
for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  var point = points[i];
  if(point.x === 1980 || point.x === 1990) {
    locations.push({
      x: point.plotX + chart.yAxis[0].left,
      y: point.plotY + chart.yAxis[0].top
    });
  }
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17ed42pa/5/)

Comment: thank you so much is perfect but i don't understand  with you know you need that offeset

Comment: @colapiombo If you remove the offset you can see that the texts gets added at the wrong location. We offset the texts with the position of the top-left corner of the graph for them to be correct.